# Get data from Django REST Framework into Vue & calling data from different components

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vue-component

I managed to get the data from my Django database into my Vue file. However, as this data will be used in multiple components, I want to make 1 data.js sheet from where I can call the data.

Code in data.js file where I want to call the InvoiceData from.

```
export default {
name: 'InvoiceData',
data(){
    return {
        InvoiceData: [],
    }
},
async created(){
    var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/invoices/');
    this.InvoiceData = await response.json();
},}
```

My Code in component.vue file

```
<template> 
<div>
{{InvoiceData}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
import InvoiceData from "../../data"
export default {
name: 'componentfile',
</script>
```

when the codes are together in one Vue file, it works.

```
<template> 
<div>
{{InvoiceData}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'InvoiceData',
data(){
    return {
        InvoiceData: [],
    }
},
async created(){
    var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/invoices/');
    this.InvoiceData = await response.json();
},}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Hi @223seneca, the script where I call the data from, is in the same file as where I cast it. When I want to cast the data in another sheet, I need to copy that code again and paste it in the script. I think it might be easier if you call this from one .js file. How can I call the script from another file? Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your data to Component.vue as prop. Your parent component would look like this:

```
<template> 
    <ComponentFile :invoiceData="invoiceData" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'InvoiceData',
components: {ComponentFile},
data(){
    return {
        invoiceData: []
    }
},
async created(){
    var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/invoices/');
    this.invoiceData = await response.json();
},}
</script>
```

In `ComponentFile` you have access to this prop:

```
<template> 
    <div>
        {{invoiceData}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import InvoiceData from "../../data"
export default {
    name: 'ComponentFile',
    props: ['invoiceData']
</script>
```